# What method does unzip use to find a single file in an archive?

Tags: zip, archive

Let's say I create 100 files with random text data of size 30MB each. Now I create a zip archive with 0 compression i.e. `zip dataset.zip -r -0 *.txt`. Now I want to extract just one file from this archive.

As described [here](https://github.com/libarchive/libarchive/wiki/FormatZip), there are two ways of unzipping/extracting files from archives:

1. Seek to the end of the file and lookup the central directory. Then use that for fast random access to the file to be extracted.(Amortized `O(1)` complexity)
2. Look through each local header and extract the one where theres a match.(`O(n)` complexity)

Which method does unzip use? From my experiments it seems like it uses method 2?

Comment: Reading the central directory is still a linear search just like going through each local header and so both are O(n).  Reading the central directory will typically mean reading a lot fewer disk blocks but the number of blocks read is also still O(n).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When searching for a single file in a large archive, it uses method 1, which you can see using `strace`:

```
open("dataset.zip", O_RDONLY)           = 3
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7fff9a895920)    = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(1, "Archive:  dataset.zip\n", 22Archive:  dataset.zip
) = 22
lseek(3, 943718400, SEEK_SET)           = 943718400
read(3, "\340P\356(s\342\306\205\201\27\360U[\250/2\207\346<\252+u\234\225\1[<\2310E\342\274"..., 4522) = 4522
lseek(3, 943722880, SEEK_SET)           = 943722880
read(3, "\3\f\225P\\ux\v\0\1\4\350\3\0\0\4\350\3\0\0", 20) = 20
lseek(3, 943718400, SEEK_SET)           = 943718400
read(3, "\340P\356(s\342\306\205\201\27\360U[\250/2\207\346<\252+u\234\225\1[<\2310E\342\274"..., 8192) = 4522
lseek(3, 849346560, SEEK_SET)           = 849346560
read(3, "D\262nv\210\343\240C\24\227\344\367q\300\223\231\306\330\275\266\213\276M\7I'&35\2\234J"..., 8192) = 8192
stat("rand-28.txt", 0x559f43e0a550)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("rand-28.txt", 0x559f43e0a550)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("rand-28.txt", 0x559f43e0a550)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
lstat("rand-28.txt", 0x559f43e0a550)    = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("rand-28.txt", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 4
ioctl(1, TIOCGWINSZ, 0x7fff9a895790)    = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
write(1, " extracting: rand-28.txt        "..., 37 extracting: rand-28.txt             ) = 37
read(3, "\275\3279Y\206\223\217}\355W%:\220YNT\0\257\260z^\361T\242\2\370\21\336\372+\306\310"..., 8192) = 8192
```

`unzip` opens `dataset.zip`, seeks to the end, then seeks to the start of the requested file in the archive (`rand-28.txt`, at offset 849346560) and reads from there.

The central directory is found by scanning the last 65557 bytes of the archive; see [the code starting here](https://sources.debian.org/src/unzip/6.0-21/process.c/#L749):

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Find and process the end-of-central-directory header.  UnZip need only
    check last 65557 bytes of zipfile:  comment may be up to 65535, end-of-
    central-directory record is 18 bytes, and signature itself is 4 bytes;
    add some to allow for appended garbage.  Since ZipInfo is often used as
    a debugging tool, search the whole zipfile if zipinfo_mode is true.
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Could you add additional information if possible about how it actually finds the central directory record(which here seems to be 943718400)

Comment: See my update. Let me know if you would like an interpretation of the code!

Comment: Thanks a ton - both for the addition of relevant sections with references and the offer to help understand! I'll try reading it on my own at first and request you if I do :)

Answer (score 3):

Actually it's a mixture.  unzip reads some data from a known location, and then reads data blocks related to (but not identical with) the target entry in the zip-file.

The design of zip/unzip is explained in comments in the source-files.  Here's the pertinent one from [`extract.c`](https://opensource.apple.com/source/zip/zip-6/unzip/unzip/extract.c.auto.html):

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
    The basic idea of this function is as follows.  Since the central di- 
    rectory lies at the end of the zipfile and the member files lie at the 
    beginning or middle or wherever, it is not very desirable to simply 
    read a central directory entry, jump to the member and extract it, and 
    then jump back to the central directory.  In the case of a large zipfile 
    this would lead to a whole lot of disk-grinding, especially if each mem- 
    ber file is small.  Instead, we read from the central directory the per- 
    tinent information for a block of files, then go extract/test the whole 
    block.  Thus this routine contains two small(er) loops within a very 
    large outer loop:  the first of the small ones reads a block of files 
    from the central directory; the second extracts or tests each file; and 
    the outer one loops over blocks.  There's some file-pointer positioning 
    stuff in between, but that's about it.  Btw, it's because of this jump- 
    ing around that we can afford to be lenient if an error occurs in one of 
    the member files:  we should still be able to go find the other members, 
    since we know the offset of each from the beginning of the zipfile. 
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

The format itself is mostly derived from PK-Ware's implementation, and is summarized in [programming information text-files](https://opensource.apple.com/source/zip/zip-6/unzip/unzip/proginfo/).  According to that, there's more than one type of record in the central directory as well, so unzip cannot readily go to the end of the file and make an array of entries to lookup the target file.

Now... if you take the time to read the source code, you'll discover that **`unzip`** reads buffers of 8192 bytes (look for **`INBUFSIZ`**).  I'd only use the single-file extract for a fairly large zip file (I had in mind the Java sources), but even for a smaller zip-file, you can see the effect of the buffer size.  To see this, I zipped up the Git files for PuTTY, which gave 2727 files (counting a copy of the git log).  Java was bigger than than 20 years ago, and hasn't shrunk.  Extracting that log from the zip-file (chosen since it wouldn't be at the end of an alphabetically-sorted index and likely ***not*** in the first block read from the central directory) gave this from **`strace`** for the `lseek` calls:

```
lseek(3, -2252, SEEK_CUR)               = 1267
lseek(3, 120463360, SEEK_SET)           = 120463360
lseek(3, 120468731, SEEK_SET)           = 120468731
lseek(3, 120135680, SEEK_SET)           = 120135680
lseek(3, 270336, SEEK_SET)              = 270336
lseek(3, 120463360, SEEK_SET)           = 120463360
```

As usual, with benchmarks, [*ymmv*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/ymmv).

Comment: While this makes sense if we are extracting the entire archive, for a single archive why would I need to do things this way? I think it might be using another routine in the case mentioned in the question eg. `extract_or_test_member`?

Comment: typo - i meant single file within the archive. With a single file just 2 seeks would be needed right?

Comment: More than that: it has to read the record which tells how large the central directory is, and it's not guaranteed that it'll read the whole directory while it's doing that.